# group records & get size of each group in rails

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hi I have table called Sold Products which stores buying information for product & schema is as follows.

```
id |username | product_id| timestamp
```

I have another table product  its schema is

```
id | product_name | description
```

I want to get most sold products. How to get that in active record?Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways of doing this... the first one being easier and more efficient than the second:

**Method 1: Use a [counter cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)**

```
class SoldProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Then you'd add a `sold_products_count` attribute to the `Product` table and find them using this:

```
Product.find(:all, :order => 'sold_products_count')
```

**Method 2: Do it based on SQL**

```
sales_count = Product.joins(:sold_products).count(:group=>"sold_products.product_id").sort_by{|product, sales| sales}.reverse
sales_count.each {|product, sales| puts "Product #{product} has #{sales} sales"}
```